# Automatic scroll to top doesn't work in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

usually when tapping the top of the screen the tableview scrolls all the way to the top. For some reason this doesn't work in one of my view controllers.

The hirarchy is as follows:

UIView
-> WebView
-> TableView
----->SearchBar
SearchDisplayController.

I think I have everything hooked up correctly (datasource, delegate, ...). I have a similar view controller where everything works. The only difference seems to be WebView, which is missing in the view controller where the tap-and-scroll-to-top works...

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to disable `scrollsToTop` on all but one of the scrollable views.  Since `UITableView` is a descendant of `UIScrollView`, it's easy to do.  However, if you want to disable it on the webview, it's a little trickier.  This seems to work:

```
[webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0].scrollsToTop = NO;
```

But that is a little iffy since it's poking around in undocumented parts of the webview.  It may stop working if Apple decides to rearrange the subviews.

Comment: Couldn't I simply enumerate all subviews, check which one is a subclass of a scrollview and use the code above on all appropriate subviews?

Comment: Here is what I do (which should even continue to even if Apple decides to rearrange the subviews):  for (int i=0; i < [webView.subviews count]; i++)
 {
  id subView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
  if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
  {
   ((UIScrollView *)subView).scrollsToTop = NO;
  }
 }

Comment: As of iOS 5, the -scrollView property of UIWebView [is exposed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scrollView).

Answer (score 30):

You have probably added some view to your view hierarchy that is a UIScrollView or contains scroll views (e.g. `UIWebView` or `UITextView`). When you tap the status bar, iOS searches for the topmost scrollview with `scrollsToTop` set to `YES` and scrolls to its top.

Add this to your class:

```
- (void) disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollsToTop = NO;
        }
        [self disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:subview];
    }
}
```

…and call

```
[self disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:myAddedSubview];
```

to solve the problem and let your table view scroll to top again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't find the problem why my tableview isn't scrolling up as I had only two tableViews, and only one enabled to scrollToTop. Using this function, I found out, that there was a third scrollview, which I was adding as a subview. I totally forgot about that one! :) Thanks!!!!

Comment: This is really helpful for finding the problematic subviews, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Don't know what Apple were smoking but by design, the behaviour on iPhone is distinctly different from iPad.  [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop) does include a "Special Condsideration" note as follows...

> On iPhone, the scroll-to-top gesture has no effect if there is more
>   than one scroll view on-screen that has scrollsToTop set to YES.

So on iPhone you have to ensure that there is only ever one UIScrollView (or UITableView/UICollectionView/UIWebView etc) that has its `scrollsToTop = YES`.

Since scrollsToTop defaults to YES you have to explicitly set `scrollsToTop = NO` for the UIScrollView's you do not want to scroll when the user taps the status bar.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently if you have more than one scrolling view (in your case the WebView and TableView) in a view controller, the "tap status bar to scroll to top" is disabled.

http://twitter.com/drance/status/2448035250438144

(Matt Drance is a former iPhoneOS developer evangelist and current iOS development rockstar)

Answer (score 3):

Swift variant of opyh's answer. Upvote him!

```
func disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf(view: UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
            (scrollView as UIScrollView).scrollsToTop = false
        }
        self.disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf(subview as UIView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to this, if you are using a `UITextView`, it isn't the subviews that need the `scrollsToTop` adjusting, it's the actual `UITextView`, in short you need this code:

```
[myTextView setScrollsToTop:FALSE];
```

This should fix the problem (*additionally, the 'disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf' function doesn't work on the UITextViews*).

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with just a tableview in the NIB. Very frustrating until I remembered I was programmatically adding a UITextView as the table view header. scrollsToTop=NO on the UITextView did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Set `scrollsToTop = NO` on all scroll views in the view, except for the one you want to scroll to top. That helps the system find the correct scroll view.