# ScrollsToTop not working when using ModalPresentationStyle OverCurrentContext in iOS8

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uimodalpresentationstyle

When presenting a modal view controller that has a `UIScrollView` or a subclass of `UIScrollView` like `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` and using `UIModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext` the presented controllers scrollview doesn't scroll to the top when the status bar is tapped, this behaviour happens in `iOS8` but not in `iOS7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why scrolling to the top when tapping the status button doesn't happen is having multiple scroll views. Only one scrollView in a controller should have scrollsToTop enabled while all other scroll views should have it disabled. While this doesn't happen in `iOS7`, in `iOS8` if the presenting controller has a scrollview with scrollsToTop enabled, the presented controller's scrollView won't scroll to the top. Since `viewWillAppear`,`viewWillDisappear` are not called when presenting a modal view controller over current context the scroll view in the presenting controller should have it's `scrollsToTop` property disabled and if desired have a callback that would allow the presented controller to reenable it.

Comment: I have the same issue. My UIViewController contains only the tableview, no scrollview, no textview... I don't have multiple scrollviews (if I have, I don't see it) To be sure I use this method in Swift : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167806/automatic-scroll-to-top-doesnt-work-in-uitableview but same result, it doesn't work.

Comment: @cmi can't really say anything without knowing your view hierarchy, my issue was that even though they're separate controllers, when using ModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext in iOS8 only one tableview could have scrollsToTop = true at a time, so just before presenting a new controller I set scrollsToTop on my tableView to false.